# ADODB.ORG - Database Abstraction Layer for PHP to MS Access DB

Tags: php, ms-access, 32bit-64bit, windows-7-x64

Trying to get it to connect in this environment:

> Windows 7 Pro - 64bit
>   MS Access 2010 - 32bit  (Tried both ACCDB and MDB versions)
>   ADODB abstraction package, Version 5.20.9

This is the test code:

```
include("C:\php\adodb5\adodb.inc.php"); // includes the adodb library
$db = NewADOConnection("access"); // A new connection
$db->Connect("", "", "", "D:\...\PhpPlay.accdb");
```

I've tried all kinds of variations for host, user and password params in the $db-> connect line, but no success. (The first two lines execute without error.) Here's the error message for line 3:

*PHP Warning:  odbc_connect(): SQL error: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified, SQL state IM002 in SQLConnect in C:\php\adodb5\drivers\adodb-odbc.inc.php on line 66*

So I'm grasping at straws now. I'm concerned about the mixed 32/64 bit settings, but don't want to do something drastic unless someone can confirm that this is a problem.

Thank you for any ideas you might be able to provide!

Answer (score 0):

Third party modules are not needed. Simply use PHP's [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) class and the already installed MS Access ODBC driver:

**DSN** Version

```
$database="D:\...\PhpPlay.accdb";

$db = new PDO("odbc:DSN=MS Access Database;DBq=$database;");
```

**Driver** Version

```
$database="D:\...\PhpPlay.accdb";

$db = new PDO("odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBq=$database;");
```